# Does armor prevent injury?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am asking if, when a soldier takes damage, it first has to get through their health from armor before injuring them.

If, for example, my soldier has 5 health, plus 2 from an item, plus 2 from their armor, how much damage can they sustain before being required to spend time healing? None? 2? 4?

Comment: I'm rather sure this has been asked before. You may find an answer browsing through older questions with this tag.

Comment: @DJPirtu you're probably right, but I did try browsing the other xcom tags, and haven't found one asking this exactly - although a few other answers implied this to be the case, which is what gave me the idea; otherwise I would have assumed that any hit caused injury.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. In this game (not xcom 2), if a soldier's health never drops below their base health (ie the only hit points lost are those conferred by armour) then they will not be injured on the strategic layer.